# JDBC Delete and Update Methods

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I'm trying to make a doctor JDBC with SQLite, but when I call the Delete and the Update methods, I get these error messages:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Doctor not deleted
>
> [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)

These are the main class and the two methods in the DoctorDAO class.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        DoctorDAO a = new DoctorDAO() ;
        
        Doctor d1 = new Doctor(null,null,null,(char) 0,null,null,null,null,null,null);
                    boolean ins = a.insertEmployee(d1);
                    if(ins){System.out.println("has added");}
                    else{System.out.println("not added");}


       System.out.println("Give Doctor's Id");
                    String id1 = sc.nextLine();
                    a.updateDoctrorByIds(id1);
         }


   public boolean updateDoctrorByIds(String Id) throws SQLException, IOException
   {  
 boolean b = true; 
 

     
       try
       {
           getConnection();
           c.setAutoCommit(false);
       
         // create the java mysql update preparedstatement 
         Scanner sca = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Give the new Name");
         String newName = sca.nextLine();
         String query = "update doctors set Name = ? where Id = ?";
         PreparedStatement preparedStmt = c.prepareStatement(query);
         preparedStmt.setString(1,Id);
         preparedStmt.setString (2,newName);

         // execute the java preparedstatement
         preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
         c.commit();
         
               
               closeConnection();
         
       } 
       catch (Exception e)
       { b =false ;
         System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
         System.err.println(e.getMessage());
         
       }
   return b;  
   }
   
public boolean deleteDoctrorById(String Id) throws SQLException` {
       
       boolean b = true;
       
       try {

            getConnection();
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("Delete operation");
            
            String query = "DELETE FROM doctors WHERE ID ='"+Id+"';";
            s = c.createStatement();
            s.executeUpdate(query);
            //System.out.println(res);
            
            c.commit();
            s.close();
            c.close();
            
               
               //closeConnection();
               System.out.println("/");
               System.out.println("/");
               System.out.println("Successfully Deleted");
               System.out.println("/");
               System.out.println("/");
           
       }
       catch (SQLException s){
            b = false;
           throw new SQLException("Doctor not deleted"); }
            
        
    return b;
       
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

One obvious error that I can see in your code - for Update, you are saying

```
String query = "update doctors set Name = ? where Id = ?";
```

then you are doing,

```
preparedStmt.setString(1,Id);
preparedStmt.setString (2,newName);
```

which is the reversed order. As per your query **name** is first parameter and **id** is second parameter but you are setting values in reverse.

Since code that you pasted isn't working code, can't suggest much for **database is locked** error but to avoid 
**database is locked** error, closing connection is recommended, even if you get an `Exception` so try to close connection inside a `finally` block.